# Create a random list of numbers depending on length of a 3D coordinate list - no repeats

Tags: python, list, random, numpy, 3d

I need a random list of numbers , with no repeats. The length based on the length of my coordinate list. i.e for 10 xyz coordinates I want a list like as follows 64231597810

```
b = 0 
n = len(in_cloud)
c_list = np.arange(b,n)
```

Is this how you do it?

Comment: Well... what happens when you do it?

Comment: it works but just wondering if its the most efficient

Comment: You'll want to add a `np.random.shuffle(c_list)` there, but yes, that's basically how I would do it.

Comment: @Jaime it seems you can post your comment as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [numpy.random.permutation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
numpy.random.permutation(10)
```

or

```
numpy.random.permutation(len(in_cloud))
```